# getting array data through ajax

Tags: php, arrays, json

i want go get some data from server using ajax. i pass an id to server, from that id userrecords are accessed from database in the form of array . now i want to return that array and access values of array using json. please, give me an example for this purpose.

Comment: no the data will comeback as json (text) then you convert it using eval, or jquery has nice support for ajax and json data type

Comment: I found some fantastic tutorials when I googled "json php tutorial" :)

Comment: and are you going to share a linke @christian, or ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use `json_encode($userdata)` to json encode data in the php file. From the client side you can use jQuery `$.parseJSON` function to parse json value. It will return a js object corresponding to the user record.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like these with jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "page.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: ({id : some_id}),
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data){
         alert(data.property);
      }
   }
)
```

data parameter on the callback function contains the json that your php page return.

In your php file do something like this:

```
echo json_encode($var);
```

`$var` must be an array or StdClass

Answer (score 0):

Follow this example. Provides a good look at the jQuery (are you using this?) code needed to parse JSON.

http://www.adeepersilence.be/archive/jquerys-getjson-with-php

It runs through a basic example and provides the functionality required to send GET parameters to the PHP script so that you can pull data based on them.

Hope that helps.